# matrix from data with awk

Tags: database, bash, matrix, awk

Warning, not an awk programmer.

I have a file, let's call it file.txt.  It has a list of numbers which I will be using to find the information I need from the rest of the directory (which is full of files *.asc).  The remaining files do not have the same lengths, but since I will be drawing data based on file.txt, the matrix I will be building will have the same number of rows.  All files DO however contain the same number of columns, 3.  The first column will be compared to file.txt, the second column of each *.asc file will be used to build the matrix.  Here is what I have so far:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{
        A[$1];
        next}
    $1 in A
       {print $2 >> "data.txt";}' file.txt *.asc
```

This, however, prints the information from each file below the previous file.  I want the information side by side, like a matrix.  I looked up paste, but it seems to be called before awk, and all examples were only of a couple of files.  I tried it still in place of print and did not work.

If anyone could help me out, this would be the last piece to my project.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you include a short example of your input files and the desired output matrix?

Comment: When you say something should be "compared to" something else, it's important to state what the comparison is - equal, less than, string, numeric, etc. so we're not guessing. As Marcus said, post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: The file.txt will have the form:
number
number
number
.
.
.
These numbers are doubles.  The files to be compared have three columns of doubles.  I want to compare the numbers in file.txt to the first column in the other files.  If the numbers match print the second field, if not, print a -1 instead.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk -f ext.awk file.txt *.asc > data.txt
```

where `ext.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    A[$1]++
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    if (ARGIND > 2)
        print ""
}
$1 in A {
    printf "%s ", $2
}
END {
    print ""
}
```

### Update

If you do not have Gnu Awk, the ARGIND variable is not available. You could then try

```
NR==FNR {
    A[$1]++
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    if (++ai > 1)
        print ""
}
$1 in A {
    printf "%s ", $2
}
END {
    print ""
}
```

Comment: You should state when a solution is gawk-specific, as this one is courtesy of ARGIND, so the OP doesn't waste time trying to debug it on whatever non-GNU awk they are using.